# Function not Defined in Class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am having trouble with a coding project in which I am trying to use classes in python to make a card game (cheat). However, when creating the player class, one of the functions that was previously defined within the class is shown as undefined. I cannot figure out the reason, and any suggestion is appreciated. Below is the definition of the classes

```
class card(object):
  def __init__(self,rank,suit):
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit

class player(object):
  def __init__ (self):
    self.number = number
    self.hand = list()
    #Here, hand is a list of the card class that was distributed with a suit and a rank
  def check_card(self,player_rank,player_suit):
    for card in self.hand:
      if card.rank == player_rank and card.suit == player_suit:
        return True
        break
    return False
  def play_card(self):
    suit = input('what is the suit?')
    rank = input('what is the rank?')
    if check_card(self,rank,suit):
      print(True)
    else:
      print(False)
```

Here is the actual code that will run it

```
player = player()
player.play_card()
```

The following error was received:

```
NameError: name 'check_card' is not defined
```

I have been troubleshooting and looking at different solutions, including moving the functions outside the class, but it continues to display the same error. Can anyone point out the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: With `player = player()`, you're overriding the symbol `player`.

Comment: Also, conventionally class names start with capital letters.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax suggestion, I'll look out for it next time!

Answer (score 0):

You have the following two issues in your code

- The way you passed self to the `check_card` function is wrong. You must call it in this way

```
self.check_card(rank,suit)
```

- The second issue is that the number is not defined. Thus I passed it as an argument while initializing the player. Feel free to make changes for that.

This is the corrected code :

```
class card(object):
  def __init__(self,rank,suit):
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit

class player(object):
  def __init__ (self, number):
    self.number = number
    self.hand = list()
    #Here, hand is a list of the card class that was distributed with a suit and a rank
  def check_card(self,player_rank,player_suit):
    for card in self.hand:
      if card.rank == player_rank and card.suit == player_suit:
        return True
        break
    return False
  def play_card(self):
    suit = input('what is the suit?')
    rank = input('what is the rank?')
    if self.check_card(rank,suit):
      print(True)
    else:
      print(False)


player = player(3)
player.play_card()
```

Output :

```
what is the suit?spade
what is the rank?3
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this document](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-call-an-instance-method-in-the-same-class-in-python) the function call in python class is self.xxxx(args) (xxxx is denoted function name)
therefore the correct version of play_card function is shown as following.

```
enter code here
def play_card(self):
    suit = input('what is the suit?')
    rank = input('what is the rank?')
    if self.check_card(rank,suit):
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: Hello. @Behnam What new points does your answer provide which was not already highlighted in the previous answer ?